# How to solve the equation $y = \frac{x^2}{20000} + 0.0046x + 62.054$ for $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

So I have an equation I am trying to solve for x.

$y = \frac{x^2}{20000} + 0.0046x + 62.054$

I can solve it up until this part, and then my mind just blanks.

$$\left(\frac{y-62.054}{0.0046}\right) \cdot 20000 = x^2 + x$$

Comment: Add $\frac{1}{4}$ to both sides. The RHS will then be $x^2+x+\frac{1}{4}=x^2+2(\frac{1}{2})x+(\frac{1}{2})^2=(x+\frac{1}{2})^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Use quadratic formula !...............